# Using Latex under OS Yosemite

Tags: latex, osx-yosemite

I just started on learning about the Latex world with this [tutorial:](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/advice/latex/starting.html).

When I try to call

```
xdvi first.dvi
```

I get the following message:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXaw.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/texbin/xdvi-xaw
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I already tried to re-install imagemagick (In case the problem was caused by it), but it didn't solve my case.

Any guess?

Comment: I have no Mac but it seems to me that "image not found" is telling you that it doesn't find the library. Could you verify that it (/usr/X11/lib/libXaw.7.dylib) exists? (if not, it probably belongs to some package which should be called something like xaw3d or x11-xaw or smilar...)

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208001/cant-compile-image-after-upgrading-to-os-x-yosemite. X11 has been moved. Type `sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11` in terminal. Should be closed as duplicate, but I get "The duplicate question must exist on Stack Overflow."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo ln -s /opt/X11 /usr/X11 worked for me.  Solved the problem and I've been trying to figure it out for quite a while.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.